# Get configurable's items quantity SUM using mysql

Tags: magento2, database

I was wondering if there is a way to get the sum of the stock of simple products in a configurable product using mysql.

As an example:

configurable sku = product_1

simple prodcuts associated to the configurable:

product_1_a qty = 10
prodcut_1_b qty = 5
prodcut_1_c qty = 5
prodcut_1_d qty = 0

I need to query the configurable sku "prodcut_1"and get the sum of the simple product (in this case 20)

Any suggestion?

Comment: Take a look at https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/87215/sql-query-to-fetch-all-child-skus-by-using-the-configurable-sku, then you will need to figure out how to get the price and then do a MySQL sum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  SUM(csi.qty)
FROM catalog_product_entity AS parent_cpe
JOIN catalog_product_relation AS link 
     ON link.parent_id = parent_cpe.entity_id
JOIN catalog_product_entity as child_cpe 
     ON child_cpe.entity_id = link.child_id 
JOIN cataloginventory_stock_item AS csi ON child_cpe.entity_id = csi.item_id
WHERE parent_cpe.sku = 'Test Configurable' GROUP BY parent_cpe.sku
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi Nilesh, thank you very much for your query example. I tried it, using the parent sku, and got "18" as SUM(csi.qty) instead of "134" that is the sum of the single qty of child product.

Comment: Are you sure I don't have to use

JOIN cataloginventory_stock_item AS csi ON child_cpe.entity_id = csi.product_id

insetad of 

JOIN cataloginventory_stock_item AS csi ON child_cpe.entity_id = csi.item_id

Comment: I have check on my end and its still working - you can try any way to get the desire result